# Glassfish v3.1 jaas error

Tags: glassfish, stack-trace, jaas

I have problem with creating easy authorization using jaas, Glassfish v3.1 and server 3.0.

I configure web.xml, sun-web.xml and done according to David Heffelfinger's book "Java EE 6 with GlassFish 3 Application Server", but still have a problem. I'll be glad to anyone, who can help.

web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Admin Pages</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/add/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>AllPages</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>customRealm</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

sun-web.xml:

```
<sun-web-app>
    <security-role-mapping>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
        <group-name>ADMIN</group-name>
    </security-role-mapping>
    <security-role-mapping>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
        <group-name>USER</group-name>
    </security-role-mapping>
</sun-web-app>
```

Realm:

```
JAAS Context:  jdbcRealm
JNDI:          jdbc/users_groups
User Table:    v_user_role
User Name Column:  username
Password Column:  password     
Group Table:   v_user_role
Group Name Column:  group_name
Digest Algorithm: MD5
```

when I try to open some page I get login form, but after enter correct (or uncorrect) login and pass I get stacktrace:

```
[#|2011-07-12T20:04:49.926+0300|WARNING|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=82;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|StandardWrapperValve[FacesServlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet FacesServlet threw exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException while attempting to process a 'beforeCreate' event for 'treeForm'.
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:422)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:394)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutComponent.beforeCreate(LayoutComponent.java:348)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutComponent.getChild(LayoutComponent.java:288)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.LayoutViewHandler.buildUIComponentTree(LayoutViewHandler.java:556)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.LayoutViewHandler.buildUIComponentTree(LayoutViewHandler.java:507)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.LayoutViewHandler.buildUIComponentTree(LayoutViewHandler.java:551)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.LayoutViewHandler.buildUIComponentTree(LayoutViewHandler.java:590)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.LayoutViewHandler.buildUIComponentTree(LayoutViewHandler.java:590)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.LayoutViewHandler.buildUIComponentTree(LayoutViewHandler.java:590)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.LayoutViewHandler.buildUIComponentTree(LayoutViewHandler.java:507)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.LayoutViewHandler.buildUIComponentTree(LayoutViewHandler.java:507)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.LayoutViewHandler.buildUIComponentTree(LayoutViewHandler.java:507)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.LayoutViewHandler.createView(LayoutViewHandler.java:255)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:244)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:113)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1534)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.sun.webui.jsf.util.UploadFilter.doFilter(UploadFilter.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doChainInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:600)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:326)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.handler.Handler.invoke(Handler.java:442)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:420)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.GuiUtil.genId(GuiUtil.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.admingui.common.handlers.UtilHandlers.encodeId(UtilHandlers.java:978)
    ... 54 more
```